# Get filename in Rails backend from file upload in React frontend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, reactjs

I have a file upload component in React that makes a POST to my Rails API:

```
class uploadFormState {
  @observable file;

  constructor() {
     this.file = '';
  }

  @action.bound setFile(file){
   this.file = file[0];
   this.fileName = file[0].name;
  }

  @action.bound uploadFile() {
    $.ajax({
        url: AppConstants.APIEndpoints.USERLOCATIONS + '/1/photos/1/upload',
        headers: { "Authorization": localStorage.getItem('authToken') },
        data: this.file,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(this.data.name + " uploaded successfully!");
        }
     });
   }
}

export default new uploadFormState();
```

As you can see in the data field, I'm trying to pass in the original file name to the rails backend. The problem is, I don't know how to get these data params.

My upload method looks like this:

```
  def upload
    @photo.upload_model(request.body)
  end
```

And the class method `upload_model' looks like this:

```
  def upload_model(model_file)
    model = StorageBucket.files.new(
    key: "models/#{id}",
    body: model_file.read,
    public: true
    )

    model.save

    update_columns model_url: model.public_url
  end
```

I've tried changing the `data` field in the ajax call to `data: {file: this.file, fileName: this.file.name}` but I'm not sure how to access these two params from the rails side. It results it uploading a text of `object Object` if I change the data params this way. `request.body` is a `StringIO` ruby type. The method itself works when the data field is `this.file` (i.e. it uploads the file to google storage), however, the filename loses the extension, which isn't ideal.

So to sum up, how do I access the uploaded filename in the Rails backend?

Comment: Is the file being uploaded successfully? Could you add the log of the upload action being called?

Comment: Yes, the above code uploads the model sucessfully

Comment: How about the log of the action?

Comment: I was able to sort it out with the help of the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to @kasperite for suggesting the use of FormData, which was a big part of this answer. I changed the ajax call to look like this:

```
@action.bound uploadFile() {
  let form = new FormData();
  form.append("file", this.file);
  $.ajax({
    url: AppConstants.APIEndpoints.USERLOCATIONS + '/1/photos/1/upload',
    headers: { "Authorization": localStorage.getItem('authToken') },
    data: form,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
      alert(this.data.name + " uploaded successfully!");
    }
  });
}
```

And then changed my controller to look like this:

```
def upload
  @photo.upload_model(params[:file].original_filename, params[:file].tempfile)
end
```

`params[:file].original_filename` is the filename while `params[:file].tempfile` is the actual file.

And my class method now looks like this:

```
def upload_model(original_filename, model_file)
  model = StorageBucket.files.new(
  key: "models/#{id}-#{original_filename}",
  body: model_file.read,
  public: true
  )

  model.save

  update_columns model_url: model.public_url
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)?In your case, it will be:

JS:

```
// Use FormData to build params 

let form = new FormData();
form.append("file_name", file[0].name);

// Send form as part of ajax post

$.ajax({
  ...
  data: form,
  ...
})
```

Then on the Rails side, you can get `file_name` through `params[:file_name]` (in controller)

That's a quick suggestion, hopefully it will help you.

Cheers